# SharePoint sites do not open in Edge and navigates to IE 11

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, internet-explorer, ie

Ok I have few sites and recently our system migrated to Windows 10. Now in Windows 10 we have IE Edge as browser along with IE 11. Now when I open my sharepoint site in Edge it navigates to IE 11 as soon as I type the web address and hit Enter

This is case with sites from one farm. other Farm's sites open In IE Edge if I type there web address. I checked the compatibility settings in master page for the sites and its IE-8 for all the sites in all the Farms. Would like to know what could be the issue. Why it is navigating to IE11 instead of staying at IE Edge.

Thanks!!!

Comment: can you change the compatibility mode to `IE-Edge` and check if the behavior still persists ?

Comment: can you suggest where to change

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you working with? 2007, 2010, 2013, 2016, Online?

Comment: Using SharePoint 2010

Comment: Now the requirement is to even if the user is in Edge and opens any sharepoint site from edge it should navigate to IE 11 instead o Edge as it is happening with few sites